# android robotium about the getCurrentActivity() delay

Tags: android, robotium

When I start an activity such `solo.click(sth)`,

and then I am in a new activity. But when I run `solo.getCurrentActivity()`, the returning message is not the current one actually. It's the former one.

However, when I enter `solo.getview(blablabla)`, and then run `solo.getCurrentActivity()`, it works again. I guess this is the waiting problem but I just don't know how to solve it. I've tried `waitForActivity()` and something similar but it doesn't work very well.

Do any one have suggestion?

Comment: You can try with  : solo.sleep(milliSec);

Answer (score 1):

Finally after several days I have found the answer. The solo.getCurrentActivity(yourAct,time) works. It's much safer than before now.

Comment: solo.getCurrentActivity(yourAct,time)  does not exist ... :(